# pageview of Google Analytics not getting reflected in dashboard

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

My console is giving me pathName hit, but no records on GAnalytics Dashboard

One of the console

```
Running command: ga("create", "G-XXX", "auto")
analytics_debug.js:22
Running command: ga("send", {hitType: "pageview", page: "/site/646c4fd09cb36771adae634b/service-type/onsiteCollection/outlet/646c4d099cb36771adae6151/menus/646c5d6e9cb36771adae6ab3"})
```

I added following code in my index.html

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=%REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID%"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', "%REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID%");
</script>
```

And also in my React.js code

```
useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.initialize([{
      trackingId: apiConsts.REACT_MEASUREMENT_ID,
      testMode: apiConsts.DEV
    }]);
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.send({ hitType: "pageview", page: location?.pathname + location?.search});
  }, [location.pathname])
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes around 24 to 48 hours to get reflected in dashboard!